# Pegar o nome do registro na coluna que mais se repete

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou precisando fazer com que seja exibido o registro que mais se repete na coluna `tipo_doenca` a partir da coluna `localidade`, ou seja exibir a doença que está em maior quantidade naquela localidade.

**Nome da tabela: TB_grafico**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você tem tentado até agora? Qual é mesmo a sua dificuldade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O que mais se repete**, geralmente, é tão somente um, portanto um `limit` vai bem!

Exemplo para localidade `bangu`

```
SELECT tipo_doenca, COUNT(tipo_doenca) FROM TB_grafico
where localidade='bangu'
GROUP BY tipo_doenca
ORDER BY COUNT(tipo_doenca) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Tabela de teste**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pedido do `@Sorack` [**exemplo no sqlfiddle.com**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/154243/1)

Comment: Posso sugerir que você coloque um exemplo no http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: @Sorack http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/154243/1

Answer (score 3):

Você pode simplesmente agrupar e ordenar para ver qual mais se repete

```
select tipo_doenca, count(tipo_doenca)
  from tb_grafico
 where localidade = 'Centro'
 group by tipo_doenca
 order by count(tipo_doenca) desc
```

**EDIT** como observado pelo @sorack, caso queira ver todas as localidades, pode adicionar a localidade no `select`e no `group by`. Também precisa remover do `where` e seria interessante incluir também no `order by` pra facilitar visualização:

```
select localidade, tipo_doenca, count(tipo_doenca)
  from tb_grafico
 group by localidade, tipo_doenca
 order by localidade, count(tipo_doenca) desc
```

Comment: Só uma dúvida: Se ele quiser listar todas as localidades a solução permaneceria igual, porém sem `where`?

Comment: Nesse caso precisaria incluir a localidade no `select` e `group by`, senão não mostraria corretamente os totais. Boa ideia @Sorack, vou colocar na resposta como alternativa

Comment: Muito bom o complemento, Ricardo. Parabéns

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma `VIEW` que conta as ocorrências por localidade:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_ocorrencias AS (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS ocorrencias,
         tg.localidade,
         tg.tipo_doenca
    FROM TB_grafico tg
   GROUP BY tg.localidade,
            tg.tipo_doenca
);
```

Depois disso selecione apenas os dados da `VIEW` que não possuem registro divergente com a quantidade maior:

```
SELECT vo.*
  FROM vw_ocorrencias vo
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM vw_ocorrencias vo2
                   WHERE vo2.localidade = vo.localidade
                     AND vo2.tipo_doenca <> vo.tipo_doenca
                     AND vo2.ocorrencias > vo.ocorrencias)
```